# how can i know the current display element when there are element behind element with PROTRACTOR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

So i got a little problem with my testing with Protractor.
i'm trying to make a new test of a program that my friends are making.
In the code (that are written with Angularjs) there is a few elements (md-sidenav) that actually hiding one behind the other and the current displayed element is by pressing buttons (i don't really know how, i think with ng-click and ng-class).

When i use the function:

```
element(by.css('locator')).isDisplayed();
```

I'm doing this on one of the elements that are not displaying right now.
And the result is "TRUE", because all the elements are displaying right now, they just one behind the other.
What can i do to solve this, if i need to know the displayed element?

Answer (score 0):

Find all of them and filter the visible one out using [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
$$('locator').filter(function(elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed();
}).first();
```

where `$$('locator')` is equivalent to `element.all(by.css('locator'))`.

Comment: It didn't work.. The order of the elements doesn't change by the one who really presenting. So the .first() not really doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use some expected conditions so that element is clickable, try to write everything in promise.
element.all(by.id('1stClick')).then(function(){
     element(by.id('2ndClick')).then(function(){
         ect.,
      });
}); 
https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions